# What is the reference count of an object in the following program?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios4

1) Disabled ARC.

2) I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)btnsecondClicked:(id)sender {

     NSString *myname;
     myname  = retrieveName();
}


NSString * retrieveName()
{
  NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString "StackOverFlow"];
  return tmpStr;
}
```

I tried with Analyser, and it says

> "Object Leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has
>         a retain count of +1"

point at line next to line where `retrieName` was invoked.

**My question:**

What is the retain count of the the object ?  Should not it be to 2 ?

because:

1. the first reference count is in `retrieveName()`

   2.the second count is in `btnsecondClicked()`, where `myname` variable holds ?

   ie: `myname  = retrievedName ()` -> Does not it increase the reference count ?

Comment: You should `autorelease` `tmpStr` or rename your method `retrieveName` as per the object ownership rules to indicate that the caller owns the returned object.

Answer (score 2):

In this step, you've created string `NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString "StackOverFlow"];`. So you've +1 reference count, because always `alloc:` returns object with +1 count. Then where will you release this? That's why It shows as leak.

Answer (score 1):

Think in terms of ownership — focus on the semantics of what you want to say, not the way the implementation has been written. This is object-oriented programming.

Whomever calls `alloc` gets an owning reference. Anybody that calls `retain` establishes ownership. So every call to either alloc or retain must be matched by a release — either an immediate `release` or an `autorelease` if you want it taken care of autonomously.

The norm for results on the stack is to autorelease. That's even enshrined in the rule that factory methods (e.g. `[NSString +string]` return such a non-owning reference.

Answer (score 1):

No, because passing an object around does not add nothing to the retain count.

However, if you did

```
- (IBAction)btnsecondClicked:(id)sender {
   NSString *myname;
   myname  = [retrieveName() retain];
}
```

Then the retain count would increase to 2, because you are explicitly declaring ownership on that particular object.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)btnsecondClicked:(id)sender {

     NSString *myname;   // nil object, no retain count
     myname  = retrieveName(); // we received the object with retain count 1 (not 2 because you are not sending `retain` to the received object)
} // you exited the function without having global reference on the object, mynames is lost because it was created inside the function, i.e. you leaked at this step 



NSString * retrieveName()
{
  NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString "StackOverFlow"]; // retain count is 1
  return tmpStr; // tmpStr returned with retain count of 1
}
```

**Now here is the code fixed**

```
- (IBAction)btnsecondClicked:(id)sender {

     NSString *myname;
     myname  = retrieveName();  // retain count = 1 and the object is the autorelease pool
}// you exited the function, autorelease pool automatically drained, the object is released, no leak



NSString * retrieveName()
{
  NSString *tmpStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString "StackOverFlow"];
  return [tmpStr autorelease];  // the object with retain count=1, and added to releasePool
}
```